# MySQL Exception During Insert Query

Tags: c#, mysql

Hey guys got a error during a MySQL insert.

Before you read the code note that...

**IF I GET THE STRING FROM toSend WHEN Visual studio breaks for error and manually enter it as a Query it works fine and inserts!**

Also this seems to only happen sometimes... although professionally it should never happen at all...

**Code**

```
 command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO offenders (dob, sex, first_name, date_created, hair, eyes, glasses, middle_name, last_name, address_line1, city, height, weight, OffDetail, risk_level, special_condition, offender_id, date_modified, designation, victim_relationship, weapon_used, force_used, nysid, scrape_state, state, zipcode, ethnicity_id, county_id, race_id, isgeocoded, created_by_user_id, computer_used, porn_involved, approved_for_web) VALUES (?dob, ?sex, ?first_name, ?date_created, ?hair, ?eyes, ?glasses, ?middle_name, ?last_name, ?address_line1, ?city, ?height, ?weight, ?OffDetail, ?risk_level, ?special_condition, ?offender_id, ?date_modified, ?designation, ?victim_relationship, ?weapon_used, ?force_used, ?nysid, ?scrape_state, ?state, ?zipcode, ?ethnicity_id, ?county_id, ?race_id, ?isgeocoded, ?created_by_user_id, ?computer_used, ?porn_involved, ?approved_for_web)";
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?dob", offender.GetParseableDoB() != null ? DateTime.ParseExact(offender.GetParseableDoB(), "MMM-dd-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : ""));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?sex", offender.sex.First()));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?first_name", offender.firstName));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?date_created", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?hair", haircolor));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?eyes", eyecolor));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?glasses", glasses));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?middle_name", offender.middleName));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?last_name", offender.lastName));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?address_line1", splitAddress[0]));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?city", splitAddress[1]));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?height", offender.height.Replace("\'", "ft").Replace("\"", "in")));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?weight", offender.weight));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?OffDetail", offender.currentPlacement));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?risk_level", offender.riskLevel));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?special_condition", offender.conditions));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?offender_id", "NY" + offender.offenderId));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?date_modified", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?designation", offender.designation));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?victim_relationship", offender.currentConviction.relationship));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?weapon_used", offender.currentConviction.weaponsUsed));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?force_used", offender.currentConviction.forceUsed));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?nysid", offender.offenderId));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?scrape_state", "36"));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?state", offender.designation));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?zipcode", splitAddress[2]));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?ethnicity_id", ethnicityid));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?county_id", 360000 + offender.countyid));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?race_id", raceid));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?isgeocoded", (offender.address[0].geoX != null && !offender.address[0].geoX.Equals("")) ? 1 : 0));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?created_by_user_id", 5));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?computer_used", offender.currentConviction.computerUsed.Contains("No") ? 0 : 1));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?porn_involved", offender.currentConviction.pornInvolved.Contains("No") ? 0 : 1));
                            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?approved_for_web", 1));
                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**Error**

```
     A first chance exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unhandled exception</Description><AppDomain>PFML_NY_MySQLUpdater.vshost.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d</ExceptionType><Message>Fatal error encountered during command execution.</Message><StackTrace>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at PFML_NY_MySQLUpdater.MySqlUtils.InsertOffenderAddresses(Offender offender)
   at PFML_NY_MySQLUpdater.Program.Main(String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()</StackTrace><ExceptionString>MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Fatal error encountered during command execution. ---&amp;gt; MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset. ---&amp;gt; MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Reading from the stream has failed. ---&amp;gt; System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately. ---&amp;gt; System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.BufferedStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32&amp;amp; affectedRow, Int64&amp;amp; insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32&amp;amp; affectedRows, Int64&amp;amp; insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at PFML_NY_MySQLUpdater.MySqlUtils.InsertOffenderAddresses(Offender offender)
   at PFML_NY_MySQLUpdater.Program.Main(String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()</ExceptionString><InnerException><ExceptionType>MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d</ExceptionType><Message>Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset.</Message><StackTrace>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset. ---&amp;gt; MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Reading from the stream has failed. ---&amp;gt; System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately. ---&amp;gt; System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.BufferedStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32&amp;amp; affectedRow, Int64&amp;amp; insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32&amp;amp; affectedRows, Int64&amp;amp; insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)</ExceptionString><InnerException><ExceptionType>MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d</ExceptionType><Message>Reading from the stream has failed.</Message><StackTrace>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32&amp;amp; affectedRow, Int64&amp;amp; insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32&amp;amp; affectedRows, Int64&amp;amp; insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()</StackTrace><ExceptionString>MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Reading from the stream has failed. ---&amp;gt; System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately. ---&amp;gt; System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.BufferedStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32&amp;amp; affectedRow, Int64&amp;amp; insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32&amp;amp; affectedRows, Int64&amp;amp; insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()</ExceptionString><InnerException><ExceptionType>System.IO.IOException, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Unable to read data from the transport connection: A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately.</Message><StackTrace>   at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.BufferedStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately. ---&amp;gt; System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.BufferedStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()</ExceptionString><InnerException><ExceptionType>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately</Message><StackTrace>   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)</ExceptionString><NativeErrorCode>2733</NativeErrorCode></InnerException></InnerException></InnerException></InnerException></Exception></TraceRecord>
```

Comment: Why don't you use parameters instead

Comment: @JuanM.Elosegui Forgot... although that doesn't solve the error.

Comment: @YaWang have you tested this code with parameters? Your code is very confuse, I'd suggest you to rewrite this using params.

Comment: @JuanM.Elosegui See edit

Comment: @JúlioMurta see edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with the following data?

```
Offer offender = new Offender {
  firstName  = "Samuel",
  middleName = null,
  lastName   = "D'Souza",
}
```

At the moment, the code has a *serious* security issue and you should use parameters or people outside the organisation can cause the entire database to be stolen or modified. If you have code like this, you'll need to raise this issue and have every SQL statement reviewed and replaced.

To learn how to use parameters in your query, use this [link](http://dotnetfacts.blogspot.com.au/2009/01/adonet-command-parameters.html).

I've posted a snippet for you to get started

```
// Define the MySQL command to get the product having the ID = 100...
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
command.CommandText =@"
  INSERT INTO offenders (dob, sex, first_name, date_created, hair, eyes, ...) 
  VALUES (?DOB, ?Sex, ?FirstName, ?DateCreated, ?Hair, ?Eyes, ...)";
command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?DOB", offender.dob));   
command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?Sex", offender.sex));  
... 
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Yeah so I parametized it no difference still same error. see edit

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to a command timeout. Try extending your Command Timeout:

```
command.CommandTimeout = 1;
```